Need help with optimizing JSON-content feed loading inside of a Newsletter template
I have a question about optimizing Salesforce Marketing Cloud Newsletters with JSON-based feed content for production sends.
The vast majority of our newsletters sent via Marketing Cloud are comprised of JSON-formated content feed, generated by our Wordpress sites. In short, we take the content from a post on site and ingest various fields into our template in SFMC. The problem is, the content is not correctly caching inside of the template as expected, so a typical send of 100,000 subscribers involves 100,000 requests to the get the content feed on our server, instead of single request to grab the content, cache it, and use it throughout the send.
We recently adopted the Server-side Javascript (SSJS) method called Script.Util.HttpGet() as an alternative for AMPScript's HTTPGet. Our understanding is that this method effectively would cache the content for use in the template – in other words, achieve our desired goal of 1 content call per Newsletter send. However, based on evidence logged in our server host, the related feed for our templates are showing up in high volume on our server, which tells us that this is not caching as expected.
In this code snippet the request to load the feed looks something like
%%[ 
set @content_feed_url = "https://newsletters.riotnewmedia.com/wp-json/wp/v2/posts?categories=16&linkstyling=1&per_page=1"
]%%

<script runat="server"> 
Platform.Load("Core", "1") 
var req = new Script.Util.HttpGet(Variable.GetValue("@content_feed_url"));
var resp = req.send();
var obj = Platform.Function.ParseJSON(String(resp.content));
Variable.SetValue("@subject_line",obj[0].title.rendered);
// set other values based on the content in obj[0]
// etc etc.
</script>

However, despite this set up, it seems that SFMC is continually making requests to load the feed via Script.Util.HttpGet during the send, which results in lots of server resources used to generate this feed. This leads us to believe that this method is not correctly set up to run performantly.
Any tips or help with how to better cache this content would be greatly appreciated!

I typically use the HTTPGet() function:
%%[ 

set @content_feed_url = "https://newsletters.riotnewmedia.com/wp-json/wp/v2/posts?categories=16&linkstyling=1&per_page=20"

]%%
<script runat="server" language="javascript"> 

  Platform.Load("Core", "1") 
  
  var content_feed_url = Variable.GetValue("@content_feed_url")
  var articles0 = Platform.Function.HTTPGet(content_feed_url,false,0,null,null, status);
  var articles = Platform.Function.ParseJSON(articles0);

  for (var a = 0; a < articles.length; a++){
    var article = articles[a];
    var id = article.id;
    var title = article.title.rendered;
    Write("<br>id: " + id);
    Write("<br>title: " + title);

  }
</script>


Try it yourself: https://mcsnippets.herokuapp.com/s/5L3EEDeZ

Thanks, Adam. We actually used HTTPGet in the past and it works fine. The problem that we ran into is that this approach has the same restrictions, in that SFMC will request the feed for each recipient in the send. During a production newsletter send, that can result in 100K+ calls to our server to grab the feed.
We keep the feed cached on the server, which absolutely helps with performance, but ultimately we'd like to cache the content from inside of SFMC.

Best method for this scenario that I've found, is to write this info to a DE using a Script Activity before the send.  Once that's done, you can retrieve the data using simple lookup functions in the email.
